# MSVC to ClangCL problems

Tags: visual-c++, clang-cl

I am trying to use ClangCL instead of MSVC's V143 toolset in my project but I get errors during compilation.

Firstly I get this error;

Error unknown type name 'uintptr_t'; did you mean 'intptr_t'?
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\vcruntime.h(386,51):

and this;

Error unknown type name 'va_list'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(292,49):

The strange thing is that I also get these errors in an almost empty test project. I using VS 2022 with Intel C++ Compiler (2024), If I use V143 tools, I don't get any error but if I use ClangCL, I get errors.

Why am I getting these errors? By the way, I don't know if I'm doing the migration correctly, but all I'm doing is selecting ClangCL from Base Platform Toolset section (I installed LLVM from Visual Studio Installer).

I googled the problem but I can't find any documentation. I asked ChatGPT-4 but did not get an enough response. I am waiting for someone knowledgeable about these issues to respond..

Comment: "almost empty test project." If I had to guess I'd say the problem is in the *almost*. Consider putting together a [mcve] that we can try ourselves. My almost empty test project has no issues.

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. If I try to use ClangCL with Intel C++ I get the errors I mentioned but not if I use the LLVM compiler instead of Intel C++. I think intel is not compatible with the ClangCL base toolkit.